# Ruby on rails order_by two attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, attributes, sql-order-by, associations

I have a table and in this table i need the finished attribute if its null to be first but at the same time i want the due date to be ordered asc

```
def all_cases
    @cases=Case.order("finished ASC NULLS FIRST").order(due_date: :asc).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20) 

    if params[:search]
      @search_term = params[:search]
      @cases = Case.order("finished ASC NULLS FIRST").order(due_date: :asc).casesearch_by(@search_term).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20) 
    else
      @cases = Case.order("finished ASC NULLS FIRST").order(due_date: :asc).order(sort_columnn + " " + sort_direction).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20) 
    end
  end
```

This code added the the finished nulls to be first but not sorted the due date

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you want
`Case.order("finished IS NOT NULL").order(due_date: :asc)`
this line of code will ordered by due_date first than ordered by finished attribute,
so in front of the records you get will be record which finished is null.

`Case.order(due_date: :asc).order("finished IS NOT NULL")`
this line of code will ordered by finished attribute first than ordered by due_date,
so in front of the records you get will be record which due date is smaller.

Comment: What I want is the order of the table to be due_date: :asc and the finished true cases always to be at the bottom

Comment: Case.order(due_date: :asc).order("finished IS NOT NULL") thisone is good but i want the finished to be at the bottom not at the bottom

Comment: `order('finished = true desc')` might work

Comment: try `Case.order(due_date: :asc).order("finished IS NULL")`

Comment: I want just the finished =true to be asc first

Comment: how about `Case.order(due_date: :asc).order("finished DESC NULLS FIRST")`